# IOS5 - AFNetworking processing request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, request, afnetworking

I'm making an application in which I have to call some webservices. I chose to work with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

I followed the Twitter example provided in the library. Everything works well except that I have permanently the little "processing circle" in the notification bar (see the image below).

[image: iPhone topbar]

Here's the code I have for my request :

```
- (id)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    _name = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
    return self;
}

+ (void)itemsListWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *items))block
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults        = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *user              = [defaults objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSDictionary *company           = [defaults objectForKey:@"company"];

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    /*
    ** [ Some stuff to set the parameters in a NSDictionnary ]
    */    

    MyAPIClient *client = [MyAPIClient sharedClient];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];

    NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"getMyList" parameters:mutableParameters];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSMutableArray *mutableItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[JSON count]];
        for (NSDictionary *attributes in JSON) {
            ListItem *item = [[ListItem alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
            [mutableItems addObject:item];
        }
        if (block) {
            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableItems]);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] show];
        if (block) {
            block(nil);
        }
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Does this means my request isn't finished ? I'm not really getting what I'm doing wrong here...

If someone could help, I'd really appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call  `[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];` this increase the activity count with 1 and the `[operation start];` will call it also. now the activity count is 2 and will get decreased when the operation is done. But since you called the `incrementActivityCount` it will bring it back to 1 and not 0.

Just call `[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];` once, for example place it in the `application:applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your applications appDeletage.

---

Also I would suggest to add the operation to a `NSOperationQueue` and not just call start on it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and for the queue tip, I'll look into this !